# Will the design related bugs be accepted for non-100% scale factor since responsiveness is available?

Tags: support, design

Before the responsive design era all design related bugs that happen only on non-100% scale factor of the page were considered as invalid, i.e. not-a-bug.

Nowadays many SE pages already have responsive versions. Will the design related bug be accepted (marked as a real bug) for such pages, even if the page scale factor is not 100%?

Comment: As far as I know, responsiveness is meant to handle changing **screen size**, not zooming while having same screen size. Those are two different things, which likely need different handling in the code. Unless you don't  mean zoom?

Comment: @ShadowWizard as far as I see, changing the scale factor (i.e. zoom) change the page layout if responsiveness is available, i.e. page looks responsive for zooming in general.

Comment: Yeah, saw it too now. Still not sure if it's intended, or side effect of whatever mechanism SE use for the responsiveness.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that's because I've post a question :)

Comment: personal experience: such a bug report is simply ignored (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7850/36296) It seems to not even deserve the not-a-bug tag :(

Comment: When the answer is "Yes" will you flood Meta with those bugs?

Comment: @rene it depends on the site's quality I think

Comment: Bug: left navigation text is crossing the line separator on <33%, but who cares... ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the default font sizes don't work for all of us without some zoom, I sure hope that SE will address bugs for use cases other than "I have 20/20 vision and use my browser full-screen on a big monitor".  Accessibility is an important part of inclusion.

Comment: [Global Accessibility Awareness Day](https://globalaccessibilityawarenessday.org/) is May 16th. It would be a good excuse to tackle some accessibility issues..,